# Linking GCP Compute Engine with Google Suite SMTP Relay Service

Tags: smtp, centos7, sendmail, google-compute-engine, g-suite

Recently we want to connect  GCP Compute Engine with Google suite email service. at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/) told that

> Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on port 25.
>   By default, outbound SMTP is blocked because of the large amount of
>   abuse server-to-server SMTP is susceptible to. In addition, having a
>   trusted third-party provider such as SendGrid, Mailgun, or Mailjet
>   relieves Compute Engine and you from maintaining IP reputation with
>   your receivers.

Our idea is we had php script and running on httpd/apache which had function `mail` to email our sales team as bellow

```
$mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

and use sendmail to relay to smtp google service. Our compute engine running on Centos 7. We not considering other trusted third party as Google recommendation like `SendGrid`, `MailGun`, and `MailJet` because we already used Google Suite.

From another [post](https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/302595-compute-engine/suggestions/17194967-send-mail-using-g-suite-from-compute-engine), connecting Compute Engine and Google Suite are hard to do. We need your help to achieve this.

We had configure sendmail as bellow

```
divert(-1)dnl
include(`/usr/share/sendmail-cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
VERSIONID(`setup for linux')dnl
OSTYPE(`linux')dnl
dnl define(`confSMTP_LOGIN_MSG', `$j Sendmail; $b')dnl
dnl define(`confLOG_LEVEL', `9')dnl
dnl define(`SMART_HOST', `relay-smtp.gmail.com')dnl
define(`confDEF_USER_ID', ``8:12'')dnl
dnl define(`confAUTO_REBUILD')dnl
define(`confTO_CONNECT', `1m')dnl
define(`confTRY_NULL_MX_LIST', `True')dnl
define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES', `True')dnl
define(`PROCMAIL_MAILER_PATH', `/usr/bin/procmail')dnl
define(`ALIAS_FILE', `/etc/aliases')dnl
define(`STATUS_FILE', `/var/log/mail/statistics')dnl
define(`UUCP_MAILER_MAX', `2000000')dnl
define(`confUSERDB_SPEC', `/etc/mail/userdb.db')dnl
define(`confPRIVACY_FLAGS', `authwarnings,novrfy,noexpn,restrictqrun')dnl
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A')dnl
dnl define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587′)dnl
dnl define(`ESMTP_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587′)dnl
dnl define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A p')dnl
dnl TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
dnl define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
dnl define(`confCACERT_PATH', `/etc/pki/tls/certs')dnl
dnl define(`confCACERT', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt')dnl
dnl define(`confSERVER_CERT', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/sendmail.pem')dnl
dnl define(`confSERVER_KEY', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/sendmail.pem')dnl
dnl define(`confDONT_BLAME_SENDMAIL', `groupreadablekeyfile')dnl
dnl define(`confTO_QUEUEWARN', `4h')dnl
dnl define(`confTO_QUEUERETURN', `5d')dnl
dnl define(`confQUEUE_LA', `12')dnl
dnl define(`confREFUSE_LA', `18')dnl
define(`confTO_IDENT', `0')dnl
dnl define(`confINET_QOS', `AF11')dnl
dnl FEATURE(delay_checks)dnl
FEATURE(`no_default_msa', `dnl')dnl
FEATURE(`smrsh', `/usr/sbin/smrsh')dnl
FEATURE(`mailertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/mailertable.db')dnl
FEATURE(`virtusertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')dnl
FEATURE(redirect)dnl
FEATURE(always_add_domain)dnl
FEATURE(use_cw_file)dnl
FEATURE(use_ct_file)dnl
dnl define(`confMAX_DAEMON_CHILDREN', `20')dnl
dnl define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_THROTTLE', `3')dnl
FEATURE(local_procmail, `', `procmail -t -Y -a $h -d $u')dnl
FEATURE(`access_db', `hash -T<TMPF> -o /etc/mail/access.db')dnl
FEATURE(`blacklist_recipients')dnl
EXPOSED_USER(`root')dnl
dnl define(`confLOCAL_MAILER', `cyrusv2')dnl
dnl define(`CYRUSV2_MAILER_ARGS', `FILE /var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=submission, Name=MSA, M=Ea')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtps, Name=TLSMTA, M=s')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`port=smtp,Addr=::1, Name=MTA-v6, Family=inet6')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Name=MTA-v4, Family=inet, Name=MTA-v6, Family=inet6')
FEATURE(`accept_unresolvable_domains')dnl
dnl FEATURE(`relay_based_on_MX')dnl
LOCAL_DOMAIN(`localhost.localdomain')dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_AS(`qreatiq.com')dnl
dnl FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
dnl FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost.localdomain)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(mydomainalias.com)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(mydomain.lan)dnl
MAILER(smtp)dnl
MAILER(procmail)dnl
dnl MAILER(cyrusv2)dnl
```

and already set SELinux as bellow

```
setsebool httpd_can_sendmail on
```

Generating certificate

```
cd /etc/pki/tls/certs
make sendmail.pem
```

Create auth file to be used for auth on `smtp.gmail.com`

```
mkdir /etc/mail/auth
chmod 700 /etc/mail/auth
```

create client info file

```
AuthInfo:smtp.gmail.com “U:smmsp” “I:gmail_address” “P:password” “M:PLAIN”
AuthInfo:smtp.gmail.com:587 “U:smmsp” “I:gmail_address” “P:password” “M:PLAIN”
```

and make

```
makemap -r hash client-info.db < client-info
chmod 600 client-info client-info.db
```

edit aliases

```
root:email_address
```

add `apache` user at trusted user 
and run `newaliases`

than i tried to send email using this code

```
echo ‘this is a test’| mail -s test_email system@qreatiq.com
```

And cek log at `/var/log/maillog` status `deferred because connection timeout with aspmx2.googlemail.com` here are complete stack trace

```
Aug 30 06:54:03 gcp***-***a sendmail[14979]: w7U6s31m014979: to=system@*****.com, ctladdr=a*****g_imannuel (1001/1002), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30234, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (w7U6s3QN014980 Message accepted for delivery)
Aug 30 06:59:03 gcp***-***a sendmail[14982]: w7U6s3QN014980: to=<system@*****.com>, ctladdr=<a*****g_imannuel@gcp***-***a.c.calm-ca***-XXX.internal> (1001/1002), delay=00:05:00, xdelay=00:05:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120537, relay=aspmx2.googlemail.com. [173.194.66.26], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with aspmx2.googlemail.com.
```

and log at /var/log/messages only session starting for ssh.

more over, here are SMTP Relay Service at our Google Suite

```
Allowed senders: Any addresses (not recommended)
Only accept mail from the specified IP addresses: Yes
Allowed IP addresses: www.****.com
Require SMTP Authentication: Yes
Require TLS encryption: No
```

Have check on Google Suite - gmail apps, and email never sends to sender. So sad. Anybody knows whats the problem?

Comment: there is a document on [configuring Gmail as a Sendmail email relay](https://linuxconfig.org/configuring-gmail-as-sendmail-email-relay) you may think a look and compare your configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sendmail here is massively over-complicating things (and will likely still want to use port 25 anyway). Just follow the instructions here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en for setting up GSuite for relaying email, use authentication, and use port 587 to send.

You also can't use the built-in PHP mail() function (and probably nobody should, ever). Use PEAR::Mail instead: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.php - that package allows you to configure the host/port etc.

Comment: I've followed https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en and really hard  to do. I didn't know why google make it so complicated even though that only relaying email to their Google product as well (Google Suite)

Comment: It's hard to do because people set their systems up insecurely all the time and spammers find the hole and send spam through gmail all the time.

This is expensive for Google to deal with, and they spend a lot of resources on it. It's money they have to spend with zero return. Spammers suck. They have made all of this email stuff harder for everyone.